# Is the dimensionality of a quantum field proportional to the amount of particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, hilbert-space

This is a very basic question about quantum physics (I'm not a physicist).

My understanding from classical field theory is that there is one field of a given type. E.g. there is one gravitational field.

However in quantum theory of one one dimensional particle, the position and velocity of the particle are described by a single dimensional wave/scalar field each.

This suggests to me that if we have a quantum field that describes for example the light emitted from the sun, then the dimensionality of this quantum field equals 6N where N is the amount of emitted photons that we want to consider.

I am not sure if this is right because I originally thought that photons are "excitations" of the electromagnetic field, i.e. that there is one 3 dimensional field and that photons are locations where the field has high scalar value.

Am I correct that the dimensionality of a quantum field is proportional to the amount of particles?

Comment: It's obscure what you gather dimensionality really is...

Comment: @cosmasZachos, I dont see what's obscure about it. An N-dimensional scalar valued field is a (continuous, differentiable, etc) function from an N dimensional manifold to the real numbers.

Comment: Are you sure you are not thinking about multi-particle wavefunctions, as opposed to quantum fields, which are operators describing an *indefinite* number of particles such as photons? These fields are an abstract repackaging of an *infinity* of quantum oscillator operators. Normally, in QFT, one uses "dimension" to denote "canonical dimension", the power of momentum dimension of the quantum field; for the photon field, this is just one.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, ah I definitely was thinking of a multi particle wavefunction! Your comment that quantum fields are abstract repackaging of infinity of quantum oscillators clarifies this for me, thank you. Is there a maximally simple explanation of how N particle wavefunction can be repackaged as a single quantum field? (I assume a quantum field on 4 dimensional spacetime is still a function from R^4 to the complex numbers? Or is it something more complex?

Comment: Sorry, not to my knowledge… the map is to an infinity of operators acting on Hilbert space, not plain complex numbers (a classical field)…